# What is CallBack in Silverlight ? how to achieve callback in silverlight mvvm?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, entity

I have a doubt..
  What is Callback? and how to implement Callback in Silverlight Mvvm and Get the Entity Values? Give me Some Code Samples also..

Comment: What do you mean by `callback`?

Comment: Waiting for getting the database values is called Callback i think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can found what a [Callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) is.

In C# there are several ways to manage callbacks. I recommend you to start with [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Here you can find an [example of it in Silverligh](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23421/BackgroundWorker-in-Silverlight).

And here anexample of [BackgroundWorker and MVVM](http://jeremybytes.blogspot.ch/2012/05/backgroundworker-component-and-mvvm.html).

Comment: Thank u JoanComasFdz.. It worked for me..